# Adding related table to ArcGIS Online feature layer

Tags: arcgis-online, relationship-class, one-to-many

I'm trying to figure out how to add a relationship class (related table one-to-many) to a feature layer within AGOL. I do not have ArcGIS Desktop or Server (do have QGIS but I don't think that will help here).

The only info I was able to find led me to believe that it may be possible by editing the service definition JSON but I can't find any reference as to how to edit it to make it work.

What are my options here?

Also, is viewing/editing/adding to related tables supported in AGOL web apps yet (not just Collector)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Survey123 Connect to make related tables to a feature layer, by defining a 'repeat' group in the xls formula. 
ESRI Ireland made a video about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YngxKU-hAG4

If you need to populate the layer or tables with existing data, you need to do this after you've created the layer and tables. This can be done by using the 'Append Data to Layer' function found under 'Upload Data' in the feature layer overview tab.

I don't know if related tables are supported by other apps than Collector and Survey123 though.